# How to flip horizontally/vertically a linearlayout in eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, android-linearlayout

I have a question here. How to flip (vertically/horizontally) a linearlayout in eclipse? I mean, I have a project which to put 10 different language into that layout. The one that bothering me is how to put Arabic and Persian language since the writing is start from right. So I think a solution which is to flip the layout when it detect that the language is Arabic or Persian. But I don't know how do it. I appreciate with every help here. thanks :)

below is the code for my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chcall_tv_asia_LinearLayout09"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#7F000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chcall_tv_asia_LinearLayout10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_service_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chcall_tv_asia_LinearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_program_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chcall_tv_asia_LinearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_audio_type"
                android:layout_width="89dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_audio"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chcall_tv_asia_LinearLayout13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_video_type"
                android:layout_width="89dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chcall_tv_asia_LinearLayout14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_subtitle_type"
                android:layout_width="89dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_asia_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

i just want to flip the `chcall_tv_asia_LinearLayout09` vertically, so that all the content in the layout also will be flipped.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed to flip my LinearLayout. just add `android:rotationY="180"`.